# Linking local Openssl to Nodejs C++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js, openssl

I am writing a C++ addon for Nodejs which uses OpenSSL 3 and I keep getting this error when trying to compile the code with the command `node-gyp build`:

`/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/openssl/macros.h:155:4: error: "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT expresses an impossible API compatibility level"`

I can see that the OpenSSL used here is included from the NodeJS folder, is there any way to link the OpenSSL library I installed with homebrew on my mac M1?

My binding.gyp file looks like this:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "module",
      "include_dirs": [ "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include" ],
      "sources": [ "./module.cpp" ],
      "libraries": [
            "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib",
            "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.a",
            "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.dylib"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem in Node.js: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40575

And here is a workaround: https://github.com/mmomtchev/node-gdal-async/commit/85816cbeff104b5484aae840fe43661c16cb6032

Add those two defines to your gyp:

```
"OPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10100001L",
"OPENSSL_CONFIGURED_API=0x30000000L"
```

I am the author of both the issue and the workaround.